# Selecting query in wordpress plugin doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create plugin which includes creating table and selecting data from table. Now i'm facing with simple select query in 'budget_show_admin.php'. I can't get the result from selecting query though i've tried so many ways showing others.Pls help and guide me where i was wrong.

this is what i write in another page of plugin folder.

```
global $wpdb;  
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_budget WHERE budget_id = 1");  
    print("pp=".$result); // it prints 'Array'  
    print("test=".$result->capital); // it prints nothing
```

Comment: can you tell me what is your table name in Db.

Comment: @Yatendra my table name is wp_budget. It is created from plugin file install.

Comment: ok, In your query you are using both prefix and table name with wp_ prefix.that is wrong .
use 
 $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->budget WHERE budget_id = 1");

Comment: hello Yatendra. I changed it and it doesn't effect. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_budget WHERE budget_id = 1", ARRAY_A);

if ( $result )
{
        foreach ( $result as $res )
        {
          echo  $res->capital;
        }   
}
```

Comment: @BindiyaPatolia i've tried with you described. But there's no result . Thz for your reply.

Comment: Try edited answer :) and let me know your issue is resolved OR not

Comment: Yeah.I've just tried with your edited ans. But it doesn't still ok. I've tried selecting query with so many ways showed in wordpress site. But i can't get the result. I don't know where i was wrong. Pls help me. Thz for your promptly reply.

Comment: Sorry, i can't at this moment :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
global $wpdb;  
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."budget WHERE budget_id = 1");  

foreach ( $result as $res )
{
          echo  $res->capital;
 }
```

Comment: Hello Yatendra. I got it!!. That works now . I'm so so happy. Thz you so much for your help. I really appreciate your help. :) :)